# Hang script on the button in unity

Tags: c#, unity

When you click on a hand should trigger the script. I do not understand how this script to the button. 
[image]
Here's a script, even though he can not correct:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class hand : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform player;
    public Transform mushrums;

    private Animator anim;
    private bool pick_up;

    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        pick_up = false;
    }

    void Update () {
        anim.SetBool ("pick_up", pick_up);

        float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
        Debug.Log(dist);

        if (dist <= 58.5f)    
        {
            pick_up = true;
            //here the removal of the object to which came
        }
        else
        {
            pick_up= false;
        }
    }
}
```

The button should be activated only at a certain distance from the object to which came.

Comment: Can you possibly try to clarify your question?  The first two sentences make absolutely no sense to me.  Can you also post a picture of your Mechanim state machine?

Comment: I agree with Jon. I have no idea what you could mean with "hanging up" a script. Could you try to phrase this differently?

Comment: I change the subject

Comment: It looks like you want to call some function when the button is pressed, correct? What function do you want to call? The code sample doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from what I've understood you want your function to be triggered on button press.

First, you can't use `Update ()` as it runs every frame. You want to rename it to something else, e.g. `triggeredFunction ()`. Then you want to declare it as public. For that, you'd add `public` in front of `void`. Then create an empty GameObject and attach the script to it. Drag the GameObject with script in the `On Click ()` frame, select the script, and function from drop down menu and you're set. Hope that helps.